# Modular arithmetics and NTT (finite field DFT) optimizations

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, modular-arithmetic, ntt

I wanted to use NTT for fast squaring (see [Fast bignum square computation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214)), but the result is slow even for really big numbers .. more than 12000 bits.

**So my question is:**

1. Is there a way to optimize my NTT transform?
   I did not mean to speed it by parallelism (threads); this is low-level layer only.
2. Is there a way to speed up my modular arithmetics?

This is my (already optimized) source code in C++ for NTT (it's complete and 100% working in C++ whitout any need for third-party libs and should also be thread-safe. Beware the source array is used as a temporary!!!, Also it cannot transform the array to itself).

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class fourier_NTT                                    // Number theoretic transform
    {

public:
    DWORD r,L,p,N;
    DWORD W,iW,rN;
    fourier_NTT(){ r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; }

    // main interface
    void  NTT(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n=0);               // DWORD dst[n] = fast  NTT(DWORD src[n])
    void INTT(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n=0);               // DWORD dst[n] = fast INTT(DWORD src[n])

    // Helper functions
    bool init(DWORD n);                                       // init r,L,p,W,iW,rN
    void  NTT_fast(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w);    // DWORD dst[n] = fast  NTT(DWORD src[n])

    // Only for testing
    void  NTT_slow(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w);    // DWORD dst[n] = slow  NTT(DWORD src[n])
    void INTT_slow(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w);    // DWORD dst[n] = slow INTT(DWORD src[n])

    // DWORD arithmetics
    DWORD shl(DWORD a);
    DWORD shr(DWORD a);

    // Modular arithmetics
    DWORD mod(DWORD a);
    DWORD modadd(DWORD a,DWORD b);
    DWORD modsub(DWORD a,DWORD b);
    DWORD modmul(DWORD a,DWORD b);
    DWORD modpow(DWORD a,DWORD b);
    };

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT:: NTT(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n)
    {
    if (n>0) init(n);
    NTT_fast(dst,src,N,W);
//    NTT_slow(dst,src,N,W);
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT::INTT(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n)
    {
    if (n>0) init(n);
    NTT_fast(dst,src,N,iW);
    for (DWORD i=0;i<N;i++) dst[i]=modmul(dst[i],rN);
       //    INTT_slow(dst,src,N,W);
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool fourier_NTT::init(DWORD n)
    {
    // (max(src[])^2)*n < p else NTT overflow can ocur !!!
    r=2; p=0xC0000001; if ((n<2)||(n>0x10000000)) { r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; N=0; return false; } L=0x30000000/n; // 32:30 bit best for unsigned 32 bit
//    r=2; p=0x78000001; if ((n<2)||(n>0x04000000)) { r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; N=0; return false; } L=0x3c000000/n; // 31:27 bit best for signed 32 bit
//    r=2; p=0x00010001; if ((n<2)||(n>0x00000020)) { r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; N=0; return false; } L=0x00000020/n; // 17:16 bit best for 16 bit
//    r=2; p=0x0a000001; if ((n<2)||(n>0x01000000)) { r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; N=0; return false; } L=0x01000000/n; // 28:25 bit
     N=n;                // size of vectors [DWORDs]
     W=modpow(r,    L);    // Wn for NTT
    iW=modpow(r,p-1-L);    // Wn for INTT
    rN=modpow(n,p-2  );    // scale for INTT
    return true;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT:: NTT_fast(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w)
    {
    if (n<=1) { if (n==1) dst[0]=src[0]; return; }
    DWORD i,j,a0,a1,n2=n>>1,w2=modmul(w,w);
    // reorder even,odd
    for (i=0,j=0;i<n2;i++,j+=2) dst[i]=src[j];
    for (    j=1;i<n ;i++,j+=2) dst[i]=src[j];
    // recursion
    NTT_fast(src   ,dst   ,n2,w2);    // even
    NTT_fast(src+n2,dst+n2,n2,w2);    // odd
    // restore results
    for (w2=1,i=0,j=n2;i<n2;i++,j++,w2=modmul(w2,w))
        {
        a0=src[i];
        a1=modmul(src[j],w2);
        dst[i]=modadd(a0,a1);
        dst[j]=modsub(a0,a1);
        }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT:: NTT_slow(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w)
    {
    DWORD i,j,wj,wi,a,n2=n>>1;
    for (wj=1,j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
        a=0;
        for (wi=1,i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            a=modadd(a,modmul(wi,src[i]));
            wi=modmul(wi,wj);
            }
        dst[j]=a;
        wj=modmul(wj,w);
        }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT::INTT_slow(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w)
    {
    DWORD i,j,wi=1,wj=1,a,n2=n>>1;
    for (wj=1,j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
        a=0;
        for (wi=1,i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            a=modadd(a,modmul(wi,src[i]));
            wi=modmul(wi,wj);
            }
        dst[j]=modmul(a,rN);
        wj=modmul(wj,iW);
        }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::shl(DWORD a) { return (a<<1)&0xFFFFFFFE; }
DWORD fourier_NTT::shr(DWORD a) { return (a>>1)&0x7FFFFFFF; }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::mod(DWORD a)
    {
    DWORD bb;
    for (bb=p;(DWORD(a)>DWORD(bb))&&(!DWORD(bb&0x80000000));bb=shl(bb));
    for (;;)
        {
        if (DWORD(a)>=DWORD(bb)) a-=bb;
        if (bb==p) break;
        bb =shr(bb);
        }
    return a;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modadd(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {
    DWORD d,cy;
    a=mod(a);
    b=mod(b);
    d=a+b;
    cy=(shr(a)+shr(b)+shr((a&1)+(b&1)))&0x80000000;
    if (cy) d-=p;
    if (DWORD(d)>=DWORD(p)) d-=p;
    return d;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modsub(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {
    DWORD d;
    a=mod(a);
    b=mod(b);
    d=a-b; if (DWORD(a)<DWORD(b)) d+=p;
    if (DWORD(d)>=DWORD(p)) d-=p;
    return d;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modmul(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {    // b bez orezania !
    int i;
    DWORD d;
    a=mod(a);
    for (d=0,i=0;i<32;i++)
        {
        if (DWORD(a&1))    d=modadd(d,b);
        a=shr(a);
        b=modadd(b,b);
        }
    return d;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modpow(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {    // a,b bez orezania !
    int i;
    DWORD d=1;
    for (i=0;i<32;i++)
        {
        d=modmul(d,d);
        if (DWORD(b&0x80000000)) d=modmul(d,a);
        b=shl(b);
        }
    return d;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Example of usage of my NTT class:

```
fourier_NTT ntt;
const DWORD n=32
DWORD x[N]={0,1,2,3,....31},y[N]={32,33,34,35,...63},z[N];

ntt.NTT(z,x,N);    // z[N]=NTT(x[N]), also init constants for N
ntt.NTT(x,y);    // x[N]=NTT(y[N]), no recompute of constants, use last N
// modular convolution y[]=z[].x[]
for (i=0;i<n;i++) y[i]=ntt.modmul(z[i],x[i]);
ntt.INTT(x,y);    // x[N]=INTT(y[N]), no recompute of constants, use last N
// x[]=convolution of original x[].y[]
```

Some measurements before optimizations (non Class NTT):

```
a = 0.98765588997654321000 | 389*32 bits
looped 1x times
sqr1[ 3.177 ms ] fast sqr
sqr2[ 720.419 ms ] NTT sqr
mul1[ 5.588 ms ] simpe mul
mul2[ 3.172 ms ] karatsuba mul
mul3[ 1053.382 ms ] NTT mul
```

Some measurements after my optimizations (current code, lower recursion parameter size/count, and better modular arithmetics):

```
a = 0.98765588997654321000 | 389*32 bits
looped 1x times
sqr1[ 3.214 ms ] fast sqr
sqr2[ 208.298 ms ] NTT sqr
mul1[ 5.564 ms ] simpe mul
mul2[ 3.113 ms ] karatsuba mul
mul3[ 302.740 ms ] NTT mul
```

Check the NTT mul and NTT sqr times (my optimizations speed it up little over 3x times). It's only 1x times loop so it's not very precise (error ~ 10%), but the speedup is noticeable even now (normally I loop it 1000x and more, but my NTT is too slow for that).

You can use my code freely... Just keep my nick and/or link to this page somewhere (rem in code, readme.txt, about or whatever). I hope it helps... (I did not see C++ source for fast NTTs anywhere so I had to write it by myself). Roots of unity were tested for all accepted N, see the `fourier_NTT::init(DWORD n)` function.

P.S.: For more information about NTT, see [Translation from Complex-FFT to Finite-Field-FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18547575/2521214). This code is based on my posts inside that link.

**[edit1:] Further changes in the code**

I managed to further optimize my modular arithmetics, by exploiting that modulo prime is allways 0xC0000001 and eliminating unnecessary calls. The resulting speedup is stunning (more than 40x times) now and NTT multiplication is faster than karatsuba after about the 1500 * 32 bits threshold. BTW, the speed of my NTT is now the same as my optimized DFFT on 64-bit doubles.

Some measurements:

```
a = 0.98765588997654321000 | 1553*32bits
looped 10x times
mul2[ 28.585 ms ] karatsuba mul
mul3[ 26.311 ms ] NTT mul
```

New source code for modular arithmetics:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::mod(DWORD a)
    {
    if (a>p) a-=p;
    return a;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modadd(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {
    DWORD d,cy;
    if (a>p) a-=p;
    if (b>p) b-=p;
    d=a+b;
    cy=((a>>1)+(b>>1)+(((a&1)+(b&1))>>1))&0x80000000;
    if (cy ) d-=p;
    if (d>p) d-=p;
    return d;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modsub(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {
    DWORD d;
    if (a>p) a-=p;
    if (b>p) b-=p;
    d=a-b;
    if (a<b) d+=p;
    if (d>p) d-=p;
    return d;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modmul(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {
    DWORD _a,_b,_p;
    _a=a;
    _b=b;
    _p=p;
    asm    {
        mov    eax,_a
        mov    ebx,_b
        mul    ebx        // H(edx),L(eax) = eax * ebx
        mov    ebx,_p
        div    ebx        // eax = H(edx),L(eax) / ebx
        mov    _a,edx    // edx = H(edx),L(eax) % ebx
        }
    return _a;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modpow(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {    // b bez orezania!
    int i;
    DWORD d=1;
    if (a>p) a-=p;
    for (i=0;i<32;i++)
        {
        d=modmul(d,d);
        if (DWORD(b&0x80000000)) d=modmul(d,a);
        b<<=1;
        }
    return d;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, functions `shl` and `shr` are no more used. I think that modpow can be further optimized, but it's not a critical function because it is called only very few times. The most critical function is modmul, and that seems to be in the best shape possible.

**Further questions:**

- Is there any other option to speedup NTT?
- Are my optimizations of modular arithmetics safe? (Results seem to be the same, but I could miss something.)

**[edit2] New optimizations**

```
a = 0.99991970486 | 2000*32 bits
looped 10x
sqr1[  13.908 ms ] fast sqr
sqr2[  13.649 ms ] NTT sqr
mul1[  19.726 ms ] simpe mul
mul2[  31.808 ms ] karatsuba mul
mul3[  19.373 ms ] NTT mul
```

I implemented all the usable stuff from all of your comments (thanks for the insight).

**Speedups:**

- +2.5% by removing unnecessary safety mods (Mandalf The Beige)
- +34.9% by use of precomputed W,iW powers (Mysticial)
- +35% total

**Actual full source code:**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- Number theoretic transforms: 2.03 -------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _fourier_NTT_h
#define _fourier_NTT_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class fourier_NTT        // Number theoretic transform
    {
public:
    DWORD r,L,p,N;
    DWORD W,iW,rN;        // W=(r^L) mod p, iW=inverse W, rN = inverse N
    DWORD *WW,*iWW,NN;    // Precomputed (W,iW)^(0,..,NN-1) powers

    // Internals
    fourier_NTT(){ r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; WW=NULL; iWW=NULL; NN=0; }
    ~fourier_NTT(){ _free(); }
    void _free();                                            // Free precomputed W,iW powers tables
    void _alloc(DWORD n);                                    // Allocate and precompute W,iW powers tables

    // Main interface
    void  NTT(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n=0);                // DWORD dst[n] = fast  NTT(DWORD src[n])
    void iNTT(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n=0);               // DWORD dst[n] = fast INTT(DWORD src[n])

    // Helper functions
    bool init(DWORD n);                                          // init r,L,p,W,iW,rN
    void  NTT_fast(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w);    // DWORD dst[n] = fast  NTT(DWORD src[n])
    void  NTT_fast(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD *w2,DWORD i2);

    // Only for testing
    void  NTT_slow(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w);    // DWORD dst[n] = slow  NTT(DWORD src[n])
    void iNTT_slow(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w);    // DWORD dst[n] = slow INTT(DWORD src[n])

    // Modular arithmetics (optimized, but it works only for p >= 0x80000000!!!)
    DWORD mod(DWORD a);
    DWORD modadd(DWORD a,DWORD b);
    DWORD modsub(DWORD a,DWORD b);
    DWORD modmul(DWORD a,DWORD b);
    DWORD modpow(DWORD a,DWORD b);
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT::_free()
    {
    NN=0;
    if ( WW) delete[]  WW;  WW=NULL;
    if (iWW) delete[] iWW; iWW=NULL;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT::_alloc(DWORD n)
    {
    if (n<=NN) return;
    DWORD *tmp,i,w;
    tmp=new DWORD[n]; if ((NN)&&( WW)) for (i=0;i<NN;i++) tmp[i]= WW[i]; if ( WW) delete[]  WW;  WW=tmp;  WW[0]=1; for (i=NN?NN:1,w= WW[i-1];i<n;i++){ w=modmul(w, W);  WW[i]=w; }
    tmp=new DWORD[n]; if ((NN)&&(iWW)) for (i=0;i<NN;i++) tmp[i]=iWW[i]; if (iWW) delete[] iWW; iWW=tmp; iWW[0]=1; for (i=NN?NN:1,w=iWW[i-1];i<n;i++){ w=modmul(w,iW); iWW[i]=w; }
    NN=n;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT:: NTT(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n)
    {
    if (n>0) init(n);
    NTT_fast(dst,src,N,WW,1);
//    NTT_fast(dst,src,N,W);
//    NTT_slow(dst,src,N,W);
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT::iNTT(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n)
    {
    if (n>0) init(n);
    NTT_fast(dst,src,N,iWW,1);
//    NTT_fast(dst,src,N,iW);
    for (DWORD i=0;i<N;i++) dst[i]=modmul(dst[i],rN);
//    iNTT_slow(dst,src,N,W);
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool fourier_NTT::init(DWORD n)
    {
    // (max(src[])^2)*n < p else NTT overflow can ocur!!!
    r=2; p=0xC0000001; if ((n<2)||(n>0x10000000)) { r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; N=0; return false; } L=0x30000000/n; // 32:30 bit best for unsigned 32 bit
//    r=2; p=0x78000001; if ((n<2)||(n>0x04000000)) { r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; N=0; return false; } L=0x3c000000/n; // 31:27 bit best for signed 32 bit
//    r=2; p=0x00010001; if ((n<2)||(n>0x00000020)) { r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; N=0; return false; } L=0x00000020/n; // 17:16 bit best for 16 bit
//    r=2; p=0x0a000001; if ((n<2)||(n>0x01000000)) { r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; N=0; return false; } L=0x01000000/n; // 28:25 bit
     N=n;                // Size of vectors [DWORDs]
     W=modpow(r,    L);  // Wn for NTT
    iW=modpow(r,p-1-L);  // Wn for INTT
    rN=modpow(n,p-2  );  // Scale for INTT
    _alloc(n>>1);        // Precompute W,iW powers
    return true;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT:: NTT_fast(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w)
    {
    if (n<=1) { if (n==1) dst[0]=src[0]; return; }
    DWORD i,j,a0,a1,n2=n>>1,w2=modmul(w,w);

    // Reorder even,odd
    for (i=0,j=0;i<n2;i++,j+=2) dst[i]=src[j];
    for (    j=1;i<n ;i++,j+=2) dst[i]=src[j];

    // Recursion
    NTT_fast(src   ,dst   ,n2,w2);    // Even
    NTT_fast(src+n2,dst+n2,n2,w2);    // Odd

    // Restore results
    for (w2=1,i=0,j=n2;i<n2;i++,j++,w2=modmul(w2,w))
        {
        a0=src[i];
        a1=modmul(src[j],w2);
        dst[i]=modadd(a0,a1);
        dst[j]=modsub(a0,a1);
        }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT:: NTT_fast(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD *w2,DWORD i2)
    {
    if (n<=1) { if (n==1) dst[0]=src[0]; return; }
    DWORD i,j,a0,a1,n2=n>>1;

    // Reorder even,odd
    for (i=0,j=0;i<n2;i++,j+=2) dst[i]=src[j];
    for (    j=1;i<n ;i++,j+=2) dst[i]=src[j];

    // Recursion
    i=i2<<1;
    NTT_fast(src   ,dst   ,n2,w2,i);    // Even
    NTT_fast(src+n2,dst+n2,n2,w2,i);    // Odd

    // Restore results
    for (i=0,j=n2;i<n2;i++,j++,w2+=i2)
        {
        a0=src[i];
        a1=modmul(src[j],*w2);
        dst[i]=modadd(a0,a1);
        dst[j]=modsub(a0,a1);
        }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT:: NTT_slow(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w)
    {
    DWORD i,j,wj,wi,a;
    for (wj=1,j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
        a=0;
        for (wi=1,i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            a=modadd(a,modmul(wi,src[i]));
            wi=modmul(wi,wj);
            }
        dst[j]=a;
        wj=modmul(wj,w);
        }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT::iNTT_slow(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w)
    {
    DWORD i,j,wi=1,wj=1,a;
    for (wj=1,j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
        a=0;
        for (wi=1,i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            a=modadd(a,modmul(wi,src[i]));
            wi=modmul(wi,wj);
            }
        dst[j]=modmul(a,rN);
        wj=modmul(wj,iW);
        }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::mod(DWORD a)
    {
    if (a>p) a-=p;
    return a;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modadd(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {
    DWORD d,cy;
    //if (a>p) a-=p;
    //if (b>p) b-=p;
    d=a+b;
    cy=((a>>1)+(b>>1)+(((a&1)+(b&1))>>1))&0x80000000;
    if (cy ) d-=p;
    if (d>p) d-=p;
    return d;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modsub(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {
    DWORD d;
    //if (a>p) a-=p;
    //if (b>p) b-=p;
    d=a-b;
    if (a<b) d+=p;
    if (d>p) d-=p;
    return d;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modmul(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {
    DWORD _a,_b,_p;
    _a=a;
    _b=b;
    _p=p;
    asm    {
        mov    eax,_a
        mov    ebx,_b
        mul    ebx        // H(edx),L(eax) = eax * ebx
        mov    ebx,_p
        div    ebx        // eax = H(edx),L(eax) / ebx
        mov    _a,edx    // edx = H(edx),L(eax) % ebx
        }
    return _a;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD fourier_NTT::modpow(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {    // b is not mod(p)!
    int i;
    DWORD d=1;
    //if (a>p) a-=p;
    for (i=0;i<32;i++)
        {
        d=modmul(d,d);
        if (DWORD(b&0x80000000)) d=modmul(d,a);
        b<<=1;
        }
    return d;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There is still the possibility to use less heap trashing by separating `NTT_fast` to two functions. One with `WW[]` and the other with `iWW[]` which leads to one parameter less in recursion calls. But I do not expect much from it (32-bit pointer only) and rather have one function for better code management in the future. Many functions are dormant now (for testing) Like slow variants, `mod` and the older fast function (with `w` parameter instead of `*w2,i2`).

**To avoid overflows for big datasets, limit input numbers to `p/4` bits.** Where `p` is number of bits per **NTT** element so for this 32 bit version use max `(32 bit/4 -> 8 bit)` input values.

**[edit3] Simple string `bigint` multiplication for testing**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
char* mul_NTT(const char *sx,const char *sy)
    {
    char *s;
    int i,j,k,n;
    // n = min power of 2 <= 2 max length(x,y)
    for (i=0;sx[i];i++); for (n=1;n<i;n<<=1);        i--;
    for (j=0;sx[j];j++); for (n=1;n<j;n<<=1); n<<=1; j--;
    DWORD *x,*y,*xx,*yy,a;
    x=new DWORD[n]; xx=new DWORD[n];
    y=new DWORD[n]; yy=new DWORD[n];

    // Zero padding
    for (k=0;i>=0;i--,k++) x[k]=sx[i]-'0'; for (;k<n;k++) x[k]=0;
    for (k=0;j>=0;j--,k++) y[k]=sy[j]-'0'; for (;k<n;k++) y[k]=0;

    //NTT
    fourier_NTT ntt;
    ntt.NTT(xx,x,n);
    ntt.NTT(yy,y);

    // Convolution
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) xx[i]=ntt.modmul(xx[i],yy[i]);

    //INTT
    ntt.iNTT(yy,xx);

    //suma
    a=0; s=new char[n+1]; for (i=0;i<n;i++) { a+=yy[i]; s[n-i-1]=(a%10)+'0'; a/=10; } s[n]=0;
    delete[] x; delete[] xx;
    delete[] y; delete[] yy;

    return s;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I use `AnsiString`'s, so I port it to `char*` hopefully, I did not do some mistake. It looks like it works properly (in comparison to the `AnsiString` version).

- `sx,sy` are decadic integer numbers
- Returns allocated string `(char*)=sx*sy`

This is only ~4 bit per 32 bit data word so there is no risk of overflow, but it is slower of course. In my `bignum` lib I use a binary representation and use `8 bit` chunks per 32-bit WORD for **NTT**. More than that is risky if `N` is big ...

Have fun with this

Comment: You probably realized that the multiply-mod divisions will kill performance. Take a look at some of the fast multiply-mod algorithms: [Montgomery Reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_reduction), [Barrett's Reduction](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/198.pdf). The second method is for large numbers, but the method works just as well on word-size integers. There's a modern high-performance implementation using [this](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~davidharvey/talks/fastntt-2-talk.pdf) that they're considering putting into GMP.

Comment: @Mysticial I do not see any benefit for modmul (I do not use big numbers just DWORDs this is not used for cryptography) but there is possible speedup for modpow on DWORDs. I do not see a straightforward algorithm on the Montgomery Reduction just few sentences about it. Do you have something working to compare actual speeds? BTW +1 for nice talk about NTT why did I not find it when I was coding this :( would save me a lot of time.

Comment: *I* don't (yet), but I'm considering implementing a 64-bit small prime NTT for [y-cruncher](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/). The slide that I linked to has benchmarks for the various butterflies. The fastest ones run in about 10 cycles per butterfly. (10 cycles by itself is already much cheaper than an integer division.) It was done by GMP developers so they know what they are doing.

Comment: @Mysticial I assume you will have variable prime not constant like me... (constant prime boost the speed of NTT 40 times for mine setup)

Comment: That's not a problem at all. You can precompute the reciprocals or whatever else is needed for all of them. Then pass them in to each routine via a structure. You could also *sigh* template them...

Comment: @Mysticial yep but then you can not use the trick to avoid modulo division by conditional substraction if p is big enough (MSB set)

Comment: The resources that I linked you already avoid the division for *any* moduli.

Comment: One last thing: You can eliminate half your multiply-mod calls if you pre-compute the twiddle factors.

Comment: @Mysticial yes I see it know will try to implement it when I got the time. I am thinking table of second-powers of W computed in init and reference index to it instead of w ... so power change would be just index +/- ... that would eliminate a lot of modmuls ... I will respond when it is done but not today ...

Comment: @Mysticial just has tested precomputed powers of W,iW and the result is awesome ~35% speed up (btw I use it in FDCT and FDFT for a long time but did not see it for FNTT :) ... ) now this is faster than FFT on same bit depth floats ... You should migrate this to answer

Comment: Added [Edit2] ... also Should I remove the old code (so the question is more readable) or leave it to preserve optimization chronology for others to see?

Comment: Added [Edit3] for testing and also repair some bugs in code from [edit2], also updated linked answers. I am still thinking about porting WW,iWW,NN to static variables

Comment: If you're interested, I just finished a prototype implementation of this NTT algorithm. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/Mysticial/ProtoNTT). I didn't try very hard to optimize it, but it uses multiple primes and can do a billion digit multiply (`3.33 * 10^9 x 3.33 * 10^9 -> 6.64 *10^9 bits`) in about 37 seconds on my 4 GHz Haswell. If you compile and run it, it will show a very simple UI that lets you run various test sizes.

Comment: @Mysticial I do not use MSVC++ so I cant compile it ... can you add binaries for Win64?

Comment: I've added a Windows binary. It will also compile with GCC 4.8, so it "theorically" should work with MinGW if it has a GCC 4.8 backend. (not that I've tested it)

Comment: @Mysticial wrong build You forget to link RTL's into exe need some dll/libs I do not have (not inside common MSVCPP runtime packages) MSVCP120.dll and likely others.

Comment: Then you probably need this: microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784 There's no other way other than for me to recompile with an earlier version of VS - which I can't since only VS2013 has the intrinsics that are needed.

Comment: @Mysticial yes it was it (I tought I had this one installed) btw you can not compile exe with linked RTL's in MSVCPP ??? That is hard to believe at least earlier versions had that option. I always assumed MSVCPP programers are just lazy to check that check-box in project option. I do not understand the meaning of this when the RTL's are incompatible and changing every year and even exe's not outputing the errors properly...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65263/discussion-between-mysticial-and-spektre).

Answer (score 5):

First off, thank you very much for posting and making it free to use.  I really appreciate that.

I was able to use some bit tricks to eliminate some branching, rearranged the main loop, and modified the assembly, and was able to get a 1.35x speedup.

Also, I added a preprocessor condition for 64 bit, seeing as Visual Studio doesn't allow inline assembly in 64 bit mode (thank you Microsoft;  feel free to go screw yourself).

Something strange happened when I was optimizing the modsub() function.  I rewrote it using bit hacks like I did modadd (which was faster).  But for some reason, the bit wise version of modsub was slower.  Not sure why.  Might just be my computer.

```
//
// Mandalf The Beige
// Based on:
// Spektre
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577076/modular-arithmetics-and-ntt-finite-field-dft-optimizations
//
// This code may be freely used however you choose, so long as it is accompanied by this notice.
//




#ifndef H__OPTIMIZED_NUMBER_THEORETIC_TRANSFORM__HDR
#define H__OPTIMIZED_NUMBER_THEORETIC_TRANSFORM__HDR

#include <string.h>

#ifndef uint32
#define uint32 unsigned long int
#endif

#ifndef uint64
#define uint64 unsigned long long int
#endif


class fast_ntt                                   // number theoretic transform
{
    public:
    fast_ntt()
    {
        r = 0; L = 0;
        W = 0; iW = 0; rN = 0;
    }
    // main interface
    void  NTT(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n = 0);             // uint32 dst[n] = fast  NTT(uint32 src[n])
    void INTT(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n = 0);             // uint32 dst[n] = fast INTT(uint32 src[n])
    // helper functions

    private:
    bool init(uint32 n);                                     // init r,L,p,W,iW,rN
    void NTT_calc(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n, uint32 w);  // uint32 dst[n] = fast  NTT(uint32 src[n])

    void  NTT_fast(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n, uint32 w);  // uint32 dst[n] = fast  NTT(uint32 src[n])
    void NTT_fast(uint32 *dst, const uint32 *src, uint32 n, uint32 w);
    // only for testing
    void  NTT_slow(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n, uint32 w);  // uint32 dst[n] = slow  NTT(uint32 src[n])
    void INTT_slow(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n, uint32 w);  // uint32 dst[n] = slow INTT(uint32 src[n])
    // uint32 arithmetics


    // modular arithmetics
    inline uint32 modadd(uint32 a, uint32 b);
    inline uint32 modsub(uint32 a, uint32 b);
    inline uint32 modmul(uint32 a, uint32 b);
    inline uint32 modpow(uint32 a, uint32 b);

    uint32 r, L, N;//, p;
    uint32 W, iW, rN;

    const uint32 p = 0xC0000001;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fast_ntt::NTT(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        init(n);
    }
    NTT_fast(dst, src, N, W);
    //  NTT_slow(dst,src,N,W);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fast_ntt::INTT(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        init(n);
    }
    NTT_fast(dst, src, N, iW);
    for (uint32 i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        dst[i] = modmul(dst[i], rN);
    }
    //  INTT_slow(dst,src,N,W);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool fast_ntt::init(uint32 n)
{
    // (max(src[])^2)*n < p else NTT overflow can ocur !!!
    r = 2;
    //p = 0xC0000001;
    if ((n < 2) || (n > 0x10000000))
    {
        r = 0; L = 0; W = 0; // p = 0;
        iW = 0; rN = 0; N = 0;
        return false;
    }
    L = 0x30000000 / n; // 32:30 bit best for unsigned 32 bit
    //  r=2; p=0x78000001; if ((n<2)||(n>0x04000000)) { r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; N=0; return false; } L=0x3c000000/n; // 31:27 bit best for signed 32 bit
    //  r=2; p=0x00010001; if ((n<2)||(n>0x00000020)) { r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; N=0; return false; } L=0x00000020/n; // 17:16 bit best for 16 bit
    //  r=2; p=0x0a000001; if ((n<2)||(n>0x01000000)) { r=0; L=0; p=0; W=0; iW=0; rN=0; N=0; return false; } L=0x01000000/n; // 28:25 bit
    N = n;               // size of vectors [uint32s]
    W = modpow(r, L); // Wn for NTT
    iW = modpow(r, p - 1 - L); // Wn for INTT
    rN = modpow(n, p - 2); // scale for INTT
    return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void fast_ntt::NTT_fast(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n, uint32 w)
{
    if(n > 1)
    {
        if(dst != src)
        {
            NTT_calc(dst, src, n, w);
        }
        else
        {
            uint32* temp = new uint32[n];
            NTT_calc(temp, src, n, w);
            memcpy(dst, temp, n * sizeof(uint32));
            delete [] temp;
        }
    }
    else if(n == 1)
    {
        dst[0] = src[0];
    }
}

void fast_ntt::NTT_fast(uint32 *dst, const uint32 *src, uint32 n, uint32 w)
{
    if (n > 1)
    {
        uint32* temp = new uint32[n];
        memcpy(temp, src, n * sizeof(uint32));
        NTT_calc(dst, temp, n, w);
        delete[] temp;
    }
    else if (n == 1)
    {
        dst[0] = src[0];
    }
}



void fast_ntt::NTT_calc(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n, uint32 w)
{
    if(n > 1)
    {
        uint32 i, j, a0, a1,
        n2 = n >> 1,
        w2 = modmul(w, w);

        // reorder even,odd
        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < n2; i++, j += 2)
        {
            dst[i] = src[j];
        }
        for (j = 1; i < n; i++, j += 2)
        {
            dst[i] = src[j];
        }
        // recursion
        if(n2 > 1)
        {
            NTT_calc(src, dst, n2, w2);  // even
            NTT_calc(src + n2, dst + n2, n2, w2);  // odd
        }
        else if(n2 == 1)
        {
            src[0] = dst[0];
            src[1] = dst[1];
        }

        // restore results

        w2 = 1, i = 0, j = n2;
        a0 = src[i];
        a1 = src[j];
        dst[i] = modadd(a0, a1);
        dst[j] = modsub(a0, a1);
        while (++i < n2)
        {
            w2 = modmul(w2, w);
            j++;
            a0 = src[i];
            a1 = modmul(src[j], w2);
            dst[i] = modadd(a0, a1);
            dst[j] = modsub(a0, a1);
        }
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fast_ntt::NTT_slow(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n, uint32 w)
{
    uint32 i, j, wj, wi, a,
        n2 = n >> 1;
    for (wj = 1, j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        a = 0;
        for (wi = 1, i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a = modadd(a, modmul(wi, src[i]));
            wi = modmul(wi, wj);
        }
        dst[j] = a;
        wj = modmul(wj, w);
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fast_ntt::INTT_slow(uint32 *dst, uint32 *src, uint32 n, uint32 w)
{
    uint32 i, j, wi = 1, wj = 1, a, n2 = n >> 1;

    for (wj = 1, j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        a = 0;
        for (wi = 1, i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a = modadd(a, modmul(wi, src[i]));
            wi = modmul(wi, wj);
        }
        dst[j] = modmul(a, rN);
        wj = modmul(wj, iW);
    }
}    


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
uint32 fast_ntt::modadd(uint32 a, uint32 b)
{
    uint32 d;
    d = a + b;

    if(d < a)
    {
        d -= p;
    }
    if (d >= p)
    {
        d -= p;
    }
    return d;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
uint32 fast_ntt::modsub(uint32 a, uint32 b)
{
    uint32 d;
    d = a - b;
    if (d > a)
    {
        d += p;
    }
    return d;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
uint32 fast_ntt::modmul(uint32 a, uint32 b)
{
    uint32 _a = a;
    uint32 _b = b;

    // Original
    uint32 _p = p;
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, _a;
        mul _b;
        div _p;
        mov eax, edx;
    };
}


uint32 fast_ntt::modpow(uint32 a, uint32 b)
{
    //*
    uint64 D, M, A, P;

    P = p; A = a;
    M = 0llu - (b & 1);
    D = (M & A) | ((~M) & 1);

    while ((b >>= 1) != 0)
    {
        A = modmul(A, A);
        //A = (A * A) % P;

        if ((b & 1) == 1)
        {
            //D = (D * A) % P;
            D = modmul(D, A);
        }
    }
    return (uint32)D;
}
```

New modmul

```
uint32 fast_ntt::modmul(uint32 a, uint32 b)
{
    uint32 _a = a;
    uint32 _b = b;   

    __asm
    {
    mov eax, a;
    mul b;
    mov ebx, eax;
    mov eax, 2863311530;
    mov ecx, edx;
    mul edx;
    shld edx, eax, 1;
    mov eax, 3221225473;

    mul edx;
    sub ebx, eax;
    mov eax, 3221225473;
    sbb ecx, edx;
    jc addback;

            neg ecx;
            and ecx, eax;
            sub ebx, ecx;

    sub ebx, eax;
    sbb edx, edx;
    and eax, edx;
            addback:
    add eax, ebx;          
    };  
}
```

**[EDIT]** 
Spektre, based on your feedback I changed the modadd & modsub back to their original.  I also realized I made some changes to the recursive NTT function I shouldn't have.

**[EDIT2]**
Removed unneeded if statements and bitwise functions.

**[EDIT3]**
Added new modmul inline assembly.

Comment: just few things I use 32bit compiler (not MS but Borland/Embarcadero) so operations like % are slower then conditional substraction. Also code optimizations are very different so I see no speed gain in this for mine setup (on x64 it can be different but I use x32) also uint64 is problem on old compilers I use (64 bit arithmetics is very buggy) the only possible gain for me are operations +,- when I have the time will test it more but I am afraid your speed gain is due to different setup only...

Comment: As I suspected your modadd slows down mine NTT about 12%, modsub is the same (did not see it at first look due to your different code formating) so no this is not a good way for mine programing and HW environment.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  I'm curious though, did the inline assembly improve anything at all?

Comment: in BDS2006 is asm very tricky because it (I assume) store some states into heap which slow thing down a bit so many times C++ functions are faster then the same asm code (because of asm directive) but for more complex or slow operations is asm of course faster ... (on MS and GCC compilers this does not happen at all from what I read and heard)

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion.  I was referring to the modifications I made to the assembly in the modmul() function.  I saw some major speedups on my machine, and I was wondering if you did as well?

Comment: as I wrote above your modmul slows mine NTT based  Schönhage-Strassen multiplication by 12% so no it does not speedup on mine setup

Comment: Sorry, you said the modadd slows it down 12%.  I didn't know modmul slowed it down as well.

Comment: Ooow you are right modadd slow things down your modmul is unusable on mine compiler because of buggy 64bit arithmetics it would just not work correctly (there is none uint64 or QWORD only Windows LARGE_INTEGER which is full of shit like long long sorry for expresion but that is how it is) and the assembly will not work because you have not access to non local variables from asm unless specific directives are used but there is no speed gain by that ...

Comment: @Spektre I made some modifications to my the posted code based on your modifications.  Hope these help a little.

Comment: @Spektre Earlier today I realized that because we are working modulo p, we don't need to keep to check if a and b are greater than p.  Neither do we need the mod() function, because if they're bigger than p, then that means the NTT won't work correctly.   I modified the code in my original post:  I got some pretty good speed improvements on my end.  Hope they work for you!

Comment: Just tested to rem few mod/ifs like you suggested ... result is still correct  :) and speedup is almost 2.6% (so +1)

Comment: Thank you!  Just wondering, would it be difficult to change the prime modulus to another number?  If you use 0x7fffffff, then the mulmod() function can be done without division (and it will be much faster).

Comment: for mod yes but for NTT not so much because NTT works only if the p complies few very specific conditions. p must be prime and also n-th root of unity. I select p so it is the biggest root of unity possible on 32bit variables so i do not need to divide just substract and also this means I can use bigger numbers without overflow. I found out that the best is use data of 1/4 the bit size of p to avoid overflow (I use 8-bit chunks for safety).

Comment: I am going to preface this with a giant MIGHT.  I've been working on the ModMul, and I've come up with a way to do it and avoid Division altogether.  However I'm having a hard time nailing down whether or not it's actually faster than the original, as the times on my computer are varying too much.  I've also found a few more if statements that can be taken out, as well as added inline to the Modular Arithmetic.  I update the code in my original post.  Again, this MIGHT not be as fast.  Let me know how it works!

Comment: you cut it out code block is limited in size and number of lines! just add new code block with the single function you changed to your edit so it is more readable for those they read this first time... your modmul now does not return anything where is the result (in eax?)? also some rems will be good not just code so it is clear what and how it does. also how you obtain the constants? (montgomery reduction of p?)

Comment: Yes, the answer is returned in eax.  That's part of the C&C++ standard if I remember correctly (it's always worked for me).  This is actually Newton Division.  I noticed that inverse for 0xC00000001 is nearly identical to 1/3 in Binary.  So I multiply the High 32 bits (since those are our primary concern), and it gives a very, very close trial quotient, that's never more than 3 off.

Comment: I found it out already... after some tests results are correct but speed is almost the same montgomery is just a little bit slower as expected (you change single instruction with many dependent instructions including jumps which is not very parallel-is-able...) but if you make modpow this way it could be much better then now I think. Also find out weird thing on my machine is faster to store variable to register and div,mul by register then direct div,mul by variable (local mem)

Comment: hmm if the result is in eax and return is not used it still works (and faster) but I do not think this is safe trick. Different compiler/version/platform can mess this up. (try to  'forget' the return of float function and soon you will see the mess it cause on FPU stack) so is this safe on normal heap/stack ? (return data types up to 32/64 bit) ...

Comment: As long as you don't have anything after the inline assembly, it's safe.  It's faster because it doesn't move the answer back to memory, then you return it, then the compiler has to move the value back to the eax register, and exit the function.  I haven't used Borland in a long time, but both Microsoft and GCC have advertised this feature for assembly.  There are a couple of improvements I'm trying to make to the modmul, but I agree with you, I don't think it will be as fast or faster, unless it's on a machine with a really, really slow Division, which is possible, but not helpful to you.

Comment: I figured out how to remove the jumps.  I did a quick latency count.  Division on my cpu is between 25-30 cycles.  This code does it in 35-40 cycles :(  Don't know how it will work on your pc.  I might be able to find a way to speed it up, but likely not by much.  Like I said, this will likely only be good on a cpu with really, really slow Division.

Comment: Yep now it is the same speed as mine approach.

Comment: Ah well, that's a shame.  Spektre, you mentioned that you were using 8 bit chunks for safety.  I've been using 16 bit chunks on my tests, and so far I all my multiplications have been correct.  Have you had any errors with 16 bits chunks?

Comment: YES!  I managed to improve the modmul!  I think this should be faster on your system!

Comment: Forgot the fundamental rule of optimization:  always put the most likely branch first.  From there, I was able to improve it even more.

Comment: yes it is faster also on mine setup around another +5% speed. Do you see any way to speedup modpow by this?  (there should be bigger speed increase possible)

Comment: I tried to use modsqr/and direct asm inline instead of d=modmul(d,d); but it is slower. compiler probably use register operands also direct operand access is working now somehow which normally must be done through local variable interesting...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56089/discussion-between-spektre-and-mandalf-the-beige).

Comment: @MandalfTheBeige the Beige, I was wondering why you guys reorder the odd and even terms when recursively calculating the NTT? The recursion should automatically have you evaluate the transform in bit reverse order. This is not a part of most FFT algorithms, so is it specific to the NTT? I ask because my implementation is failing only for odd indexes...?

Comment: @z.karl reordering odd and even is a part of FFT algo without it will not work (its not just for NTT) ... its derived from the FFT equation subdivision for more info see [How to compute Discrete Fourier Transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26355569/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre for the iterative version yes you need to put the original array into bit-reversal order but for a recursive version the recursion takes care of the ordering for you. I only say this because I've seen it proved in CLRS.

Comment: @z.karl no you need to separate even and odds to 2 separate buffers and apply recursion on each of them

Comment: @Spektre I think we're saying the same thing e.g. for a recursive implementation on (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) the first recursion acts on (0,2,4,6) then on  (0,4) then on (0), (4), (2,6), (2), (6), THEN (1,3,5,7). The recursion implicitly accesses the array/buffer in bit-reversal order