# Using the FFT algorithm to calculate

Tags: algorithm, fft, complexity-theory

Given a set  of n particles electric charge carriers founds on the points (1,0), (2,0), .... (n,0) on a plane. 
The particle charge that found in point (i,0) is noted as Qi. the force that act on the particle is given by the formula:

[image]
C is a Coulomb's constant.

Give an algorithm to calculate Fi, for all of the particles in total complexity O(nlgn).
Hint: use FFT algorithm.

It seems that Fi is already divided to the even and odd points..

I thought about to divide each sum to calculate the FFT (but divide until what..?) and
then sum always half of the points (cause this is what FFT cause) and then subtract the result of the sums that given on the formula..

any idea of how to do it better?

Comment: what exactly are you asking?  Can it be computed faster then O(n.log(n)) ?  The answer is maybe but we do not know yet ... If you are asking how to improve this then its more about optimizing of concrete implementation which you did not provide. So everything is just guess work. From mine first look ... aren't your plane charges similar to 2D image? (so can try divide it to lines and rows) which gives you O(m.log(m)) where m*m = n for square resolution ... but from the dataset you provide it is just single line which is not the case. PS divide until the dataset is 1 or 2 points ...

Comment: Spektre thanks for your comment, i'm asking about if there is another way of thinking from what i thought to do.. I don't familiar enough with FFT algorithm. 
I know that in FFT we divide each time the dataset until we get a set of points and then can calculate half of them.. something like that. But how can i know if it's reached to this case?

Comment: The same question was already asked in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/792903/115115, where multiple hints about the convolution structure of the problem were given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like homework so no actual code for your case is provided instead some example and hints.
for **FFT**-like algorithms:

1. **set the dataset size to power of `2` by zero padding**

   so the division to halves is simple (no remainders)
2. **create recursive function to compute your FFT-like stuff**

   in it reorder the data set, divide it to two halves and recursively call it self 2 times (each with the different half of data) and add if statement to start. If dataset `size<=1` or `2` then return directly computed value to ensure that recursion stops.

   After these two recursion calls reorder data back and combine them to result
3. **remove zero padding from the result if needed**

For example this is how mine **NTT** looks like (Number theoretic transform)

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT:: NTT_fast(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w)
    {
    // recursion stop condition if the data is single number ...
    if (n<=1) { if (n==1) dst[0]=src[0]; return; }
    DWORD i,j,a0,a1,n2=n>>1,w2=modmul(w,w);
    // reorder even,odd to dst array
    for (i=0,j=0;i<n2;i++,j+=2) dst[i]=src[j];
    for (    j=1;i<n ;i++,j+=2) dst[i]=src[j];
    // recursion
    NTT_fast(src   ,dst   ,n2,w2);  // even
    NTT_fast(src+n2,dst+n2,n2,w2);  // odd
    // restore results
    for (w2=1,i=0,j=n2;i<n2;i++,j++,w2=modmul(w2,w))
        {
        a0=src[i];
        a1=modmul(src[j],w2);
        dst[i]=modadd(a0,a1);
        dst[j]=modsub(a0,a1);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Full source code and more info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214).

**Always compare Fast implementation results with the slow implementation !!!**

A small error in some coefficient or index can lead to huge differences in results with growing dataset size.

This is slow implementation for above **NTT** function:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fourier_NTT:: NTT_slow(DWORD *dst,DWORD *src,DWORD n,DWORD w)
    {
    DWORD i,j,wj,wi,a,n2=n>>1;
    for (wj=1,j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
        a=0;
        for (wi=1,i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            a=modadd(a,modmul(wi,src[i]));
            wi=modmul(wi,wj);
            }
        dst[j]=a;
        wj=modmul(wj,w);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**[Notes]**

1. **now you have your separation equation**

   derive the coefficient difference between directly computed value and value computed by 2x half recursion call and restore your result accordingly so the output match the correct result.