# Loss of data during the Inverse-FFT of an Image

Tags: c#-4.0, image-processing, bitmap, fft, ifft

I am using the following code to convert a Bitmap to Complex and vice versa.

Even though those were directly copied from [Accord.NET framework](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Sources/Accord.Imaging/AForge.Imaging/ComplexImage.cs), while testing these static methods, I have discovered that, repeated use of these static methods cause 'data-loss'. As a result, the end output/result becomes **distorted**.

```
public partial class ImageDataConverter
{
    #region private static Complex[,] FromBitmapData(BitmapData bmpData)
    private static Complex[,] ToComplex(BitmapData bmpData)
    {
        Complex[,] comp = null;

        if (bmpData.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
        {
            int width = bmpData.Width;
            int height = bmpData.Height;
            int offset = bmpData.Stride - (width * 1);//1 === 1 byte per pixel.

            if ((!Tools.IsPowerOf2(width)) || (!Tools.IsPowerOf2(height)))
            {
                throw new Exception("Imager width and height should be n of 2.");
            }

            comp = new Complex[width, height];

            unsafe
            {
                byte* src = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0.ToPointer();

                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++, src++)
                    {
                        comp[y, x] = new Complex((float)*src / 255,
                                                    comp[y, x].Imaginary);
                    }
                    src += offset;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("EightBppIndexedImageRequired");
        }

        return comp;
    }
    #endregion

    public static Complex[,] ToComplex(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        Complex[,] comp = null;

        if (bmp.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
        {
            BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(  new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                                PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            try
            {
                comp = ToComplex(bmpData);
            }
            finally
            {
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("EightBppIndexedImageRequired");
        }

        return comp;
    }

    public static Bitmap ToBitmap(Complex[,] image, bool fourierTransformed)
    {
        int width = image.GetLength(0);
        int height = image.GetLength(1);

        Bitmap bmp = Imager.CreateGrayscaleImage(width, height);

        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        int offset = bmpData.Stride - width;
        double scale = (fourierTransformed) ? Math.Sqrt(width * height) : 1;

        unsafe
        {
            byte* address = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0.ToPointer();

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++, address++)
                {
                    double min = System.Math.Min(255, image[y, x].Magnitude * scale * 255);

                    *address = (byte)System.Math.Max(0, min);
                }
                address += offset;
            }
        }

        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        return bmp;
    }
}
```

([The DotNetFiddle link of the complete source code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZXlcdP))

([ImageDataConverter](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E4kCMe))

**Output:**

[image]

As you can see, FFT is working correctly, but, I-FFT isn't.

That is because bitmap to complex and vice versa isn't working as expected.

**What could be done to correct the ToComplex() and ToBitmap() functions so that they don't loss data?**

Comment: The fiddle doesn't contain the `ImageDataConverter` class.  Can we have a look? I suspect there's a problem with the dynamic range of the data once you convert back.

Comment: I hope you know FFT result is complex ... your FFT result looks like just grayscale scalar which is not complex so you are most likely throwing away imaginary part or using power spectrum instead of complex domain anyway from such data you can not reconstruct original image. Not to mention the shift ... Take a look at [What should be the input and output for an FFT image transformation?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26734979/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre All the more reason to examine what the `ImageDataConverter` class looks like. That I believe is the culprit behind the questionable results. Looking at the fiddle, the FFT code seems to be fine but the code to handle the transformation when displaying the image data is missing. BTW, great link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not code in **C#** so handle this answer with extreme prejudice!

Just from a quick look I spotted few problems:

1. **`ToComplex()`**

   Is converting BMP into 2D complex matrix. When you are converting you are leaving imaginary part unchanged, but at the start of the same function you have:

   ```
   Complex[,] complex2D = null;
   complex2D = new Complex[width, height];
   ```

   So the imaginary parts are either undefined or zero depends on your complex class constructor. **This means you are missing half of the data needed for reconstruction !!!** You should restore the original complex matrix from 2 images one for real and second for imaginary part of the result.
2. **`ToBitmap()`**

   You are saving magnitude which is I think `sqrt( Re*Re + Im*Im )` so it is power spectrum not the original complex values and so you can not reconstruct back... You should store Re,Im in 2 separate images.
3. **8bit per pixel**

   That is not much and can cause significant round off errors after **FFT/IFFT** so reconstruction can be really distorted.

**[Edit1] Remedy**

There are more options to repair this for example:

1. **use floating complex matrix for computations and bitmap only for visualization.**

   This is the safest way because you avoid additional conversion round offs. This approach has the best precision. But you need to rewrite your DIP/CV algorithms to support complex domain matrices instead of bitmaps which require not small amount of work.
2. **rewrite your conversions to support real and imaginary part images**

   Your conversion is really bad as it does not store/restore Real and Imaginary parts as it should and also **it does not account for negative values** (at least I do not see it instead they are cut down to zero which is WRONG). I would rewrite the conversion to this:

   ```
   // conversion scales
   float Re_ofset=256.0,Re_scale=512.0/255.0;
   float Im_ofset=256.0,Im_scale=512.0/255.0;

   private static Complex[,] ToComplex(BitmapData bmpRe,BitmapData bmpIm)
    {
    //...
    byte* srcRe = (byte*)bmpRe.Scan0.ToPointer();
    byte* srcIm = (byte*)bmpIm.Scan0.ToPointer();
    complex c = new Complex(0.0,0.0);
    // for each line
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
     {
     // for each pixel
     for (int x = 0; x < width; x++, src++)
      {
      complex2D[y, x] = c;
      c.Real      = (float)*(srcRe*Re_scale)-Re_ofset;
      c.Imaginary = (float)*(srcIm*Im_scale)-Im_ofset;
      }
     src += offset;
     }         
    //...
    }
   public static Bitmap ToBitmapRe(Complex[,] complex2D)
    {
    //...
    float Re = (complex2D[y, x].Real+Re_ofset)/Re_scale;
    Re = min(Re,255.0);
    Re = max(Re,  0.0);
    *address = (byte)Re;
    //...
    }
   public static Bitmap ToBitmapIm(Complex[,] complex2D)
    {
    //...
    float Im = (complex2D[y, x].Imaginary+Im_ofset)/Im_scale;
    Re = min(Im,255.0);
    Re = max(Im,  0.0);
    *address = (byte)Im;
    //...
    }
   ```

   Where:

   ```
   Re_ofset = min(complex2D[,].Real);
   Im_ofset = min(complex2D[,].Imaginary);
   Re_scale = (max(complex2D[,].Real     )-min(complex2D[,].Real     ))/255.0;
   Im_scale = (max(complex2D[,].Imaginary)-min(complex2D[,].Imaginary))/255.0;
   ```

   or cover bigger interval then the complex matrix values.

   You can also encode both Real and Imaginary parts to single image for example first half of image could be Real and next the Imaginary part. In that case you do not need to change the function headers nor names at all .. but you would need to handle the images as 2 joined squares each with different meaning ...

   You can also use RGB images where `R = Real, B = Imaginary` or any other encoding that suites you.

**[Edit2] some examples to make my points more clear**

1. **example of approach #1**

   The image is in form of floating point 2D complex matrix and the images are created only for visualization. There is little rounding error this way. The values are not normalized so the range is `<0.0,255.0>` per pixel/cell at first but after transforms and scaling it could change greatly.

   [image: approach #1]

   As you can see I added scaling so all pixels are multiplied by 315 to actually see anything because the **FFT** output values are small except of few cells. But only for visualization the complex matrix is unchanged.
2. **example of approach #2**

   Well as I mentioned before you do not handle negative values, normalize values to range `<0,1>` and back by scaling and rounding off and using only `8` bits per pixel to store the sub results. I tried to simulate that with my code and here is what I got (using complex domain instead of wrongly used power spectrum like you did). Here C++ source only as an template example as you do not have the functions and classes behind it:

   ```
   transform t;
   cplx_2D  c;
   rgb2i(bmp0);
   c.ld(bmp0,bmp0);
   null_im(c);
   c.mul(1.0/255.0);

   c.mul(255.0); c.st(bmp0,bmp1); c.ld(bmp0,bmp1); i2iii(bmp0); i2iii(bmp1); c.mul(1.0/255.0);
   bmp0->SaveToFile("_out0_Re.bmp");
   bmp1->SaveToFile("_out0_Im.bmp");

   t. DFFT(c,c);
   c.wrap();

   c.mul(255.0); c.st(bmp0,bmp1); c.ld(bmp0,bmp1); i2iii(bmp0); i2iii(bmp1); c.mul(1.0/255.0);
   bmp0->SaveToFile("_out1_Re.bmp");
   bmp1->SaveToFile("_out1_Im.bmp");

   c.wrap();
   t.iDFFT(c,c);

   c.mul(255.0); c.st(bmp0,bmp1); c.ld(bmp0,bmp1); i2iii(bmp0); i2iii(bmp1); c.mul(1.0/255.0);
   bmp0->SaveToFile("_out2_Re.bmp");
   bmp1->SaveToFile("_out2_Im.bmp");
   ```

   And here the sub results:

   [image: approach #2 8bit]

   As you can see after the **DFFT** and wrap the image is really dark and most of the values are rounded off. So the result after unwrap and **IDFFT** is really pure.

   Here some explanations to code:

   - `c.st(bmpre,bmpim)`  is the same as your `ToBitmap`
   - `c.ld(bmpre,bmpim)`  is the same as your `ToComplex`
   - `c.mul(scale)` multiplies complex matrix `c` by `scale`
   - `rgb2i` converts RGB to grayscale intensity `<0,255>`
   - `i2iii` converts grayscale intensity ro grayscale RGB image

Comment: First of all, 90% code is copied From accord.net. secondly, those functions are working well, individually.

Comment: @anonymous I do not doubt they work as should but they are not doing what you want/need them to do. You are doing IFFT on data that is not direct result of FFT so you can not expect the result will be the original image or even anything close to it

Comment: Yes. Even though 1 and 2 were directly copied from accord.net framework, they are not working as expected. That is a real BS and frustrating experience.

Comment: @anonymous btw I stopped using 3th party frameworks and stuff where I can  a long time ago for similar and many other reasons ... the time to make something work is usually higher then code it yourself in most cases not to mention you can manage your own code. Not to mention continuity of code (my apps must be working for decades ... and frameworks are usually incompatible between versions or even discontinued and you're screwed after few years if you depend on them...)

Comment: if I want to display/use a Bitmap, which one would I display/use, BitmapRe or BitmapIm ?

Comment: @anonymous whichever you want I display usually both or just Re ... some apps are displaying the powerspectum instead `sqrt(Re*Re + Im*Im)`

Comment: Probably, I couldn't get my point across. .....  The GUI, you see in my question, was supposed to show the Grayscale image in the last quadrant after the application of I-FFT. ..... Which Bitmap would be able to show the original Grayscale image again, Real or Imaginary? ......Should we merge the two Bitmaps in some way?

Comment: @anonymous you need both for reconstruction no merging simply load the complex matrix for IFFT real values from one image and Imaginary from the other as I wrote in that code ...

Comment: @anonymous added **[Edit2]** with some examples

Comment: At the beginning of the code, you are declaring some constants: `// conversion scales
float Re_ofset=256.0,Re_scale=512.0/255.0;
float Im_ofset=256.0,Im_scale=512.0/255.0;`
....
But, at the end of the code you are saying that, 
.....
`Re_ofset = min(complex2D[,].Real);
Im_ofset = min(complex2D[,].Imaginary);
Re_scale = (max(complex2D[,].Real     )-min(complex2D[,].Real     ))/255.0;
Im_scale = (max(complex2D[,].Imaginary)-min(complex2D[,].Imaginary))/255.0;`
.......
So, which one is correct?

Comment: @anonymous booth are correct. The closer you are to the `min,max` values the better you are using the 8 bits of data ...

Comment: suppose, I have just started my application and read an image named `lena.png` into a `Bitmap`-type object `bmpReal`. Now, I need to convert `bmpReal` to a `Complex [,]`-type object `compBmp`. .....  According to your source code, to create a `Complex [,]`-type object, I need two objects of type `Bitmap`: `bmpReal` and `bmpImaginary`. ....... But, I have only one object named `bmpReal` at this point. Where can I find the other one at that point? Your `c.st(bmpReal, bmpImaginary); c.ld(bmpReal, bmpImaginary);` seems to be doing some magic and creating the other object. What is that magic?

Comment: @anonymous at first you can use any Imaginary part (for example `Im=0` like me it does not matter)  but after the first **DFFT** the result is complex so you need to use the Imaginary as is. That is basic knowledge with **FFT** use that you should already know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good in this puzzles but double check this dividing.

```
comp[y, x] = new Complex((float)*src / 255, comp[y, x].Imaginary);
```

You can loose precision as it is described here
[Complex class definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex.complex(v=vs.110).aspx) in **Remarks** section.
May be this happens in your case.
Hope this helps.