# FFT Algorithm C Code Explaination

Tags: c, algorithm, signal-processing, fft, ifft

http://www.tech.dmu.ac.uk/~eg/tensiometer/fft/fft.c

http://www.tech.dmu.ac.uk/~eg/tensiometer/fft/fft_test.c

I have found a good working C Code for FFT Algorithm for converting Time Domain to Frequency Domain and vice versa in the above links. But I wanted to know the flowchart or step by step process of how this code works. I am trying to analyze the code with butterfly method of decimation in time for FFT but i am facing difficulties in understanding the code. The code is working very well and giving me the correct results but it would be very helpful to me if someone could give a brief or detailed explaination on how this code works.

I am confused with the array and the pointers used in the fft.c code. Also I am not getting what are the variables **offset** and **delta** mean in the code. How the rectangular matrix of real and imaginary terms are considered/used in the code?? Please guide me.

Thanks,
Psbk

Comment: Perhaps this question is better asked at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/algorithms

Comment: At the risk of sounding a bit too 20th Century, go find a copy of the book The Fast Fourier Transform and its Applications by E. Brigham.  I have yet to find a better explanation and after reading it, all will become clear.  It's a bit pricey to buy, so your local library may be a better place to start.

Comment: @andand: I second that recommendation - it's a superb book and is a rarity in that it spends a lot of time looking at practical applications of the FFT rather than just the theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26355569/2521214

Now from the first look the offset and delta is used to:

- make the butterfly shuffle permutation
- you start with step 1 and half of the interval
- and by recursion you will get to log2(N) step and interval of 1 item ...
- +/- one recursion level
- I usually do the butterfly in reverse order

The XX array

- is a buffer to store the subresult or input data
- you can not perform FFT inplace easily (if at all)
- so you compute to/from the temp buffer instead
- and on each recursion just swap the data and temp buffers (physically or their meaning)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation on my question. It is useful to me very much. I will go through the code again with the information given by you and ask for any other information if I get stuck somewhere. I am going through the link that you have mentioned and feel it is very good. Thanks a lot again.