# Implementing 2D inverse fourier transform using 1D transforms

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, fft

I am trying to implement, in Python, some functions that transform images to their Fourier domain and vice-versa, for image processing tasks.

I implemented the 2D-DFT using repeated 1D-DFT, and it worked fine, but when I tried to implement 2D inverse DFT using repeated inverse 1D-DFT, some weird problem occurred: when I transform an image to its Fourier domain and then back to the image domain, it looks like the image was reflected and merged with its reflection, as can be seen here:

This is the input:

[image: img]

and this is the output

[image: img]

This is the function that is responsible for the mess:

```
def IDFT2(fourier_image):
    image = np.zeros(fourier_image.shape)
    for col in range(image.shape[1]):
        image[:, col] = IDFT1(fourier_image[:, col])

    for row in range(image.shape[0]):
        image[row, :] = IDFT1(image[row,:])

    return image
```

What did I do wrong? I am pretty sure that IDFT1 works fine, and so is the regular 2D-DFT.

Comment: Why do you have IDFT1(fourier_image[:, col]) for columns and IDFT1(image[row,:]) for rows and not IDFT1(fourier_image[row, :])? Please provide your code for the IDFT1 as well.

Comment: As I understood it, at the second pass (the rows) I need to operate over the output of the previous stage (the pass over the colums). Am I wrong?

Comment: @montecarlo you have edit out the images (I add them back) most likely by mistake. That `![bla bla][1]` in mark-down code means first link to image from list of links at the end. the `!` means image without it is just link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not use **Python** so I am not confident to analyze your code but my bet is that you most likely forget to implement complex values at some stage....

it should be:

1. **DFT** rows from real to complex domain
2. **DFT** columns of result from complex to complex domain
3. apply normalization if needed
4. any or none processing ...
5. **iDFT** rows from complex to complex domain
6. **iDFT** columns of result from complex to real domain
7. apply normalization if needed

if you use just real to complex domain **DFT/iDFT** in the second passes (bullets **#2,#6**) then it would create the mirroring because **DFT** of real values is  a mirrored sequence ... Btw. it does not matter if you process rows or columns first ... also you can process rows first in **DFT** and columns first in **iDFT** the result should be the same +/- floating errors ...

for more info see

- [How to compute Discrete Fourier Transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26355569/2521214)

and all the sub-links there especially the `2D FFT and wrapping example` so you can compare your results with something working

Comment: you are most correct! the line `np.real(signal).astype(np.float32)` transform the complex numbers to real ones when it shouldn't. removing the line fixed the problem.

Comment: @NadavBorenstein glad to be of help