# Inverse Discrete Fourier transform output image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, dft

I am trying implement inverse discrete Fourier transfrom for the image which i applied discrete Fourier transform beforehand. The output is kind of two images. One image is in correct position the other is reversed position. Could you help me to solve this issue?

Here is the code i have written.

```
double inverseFourierReal = 0.0;
    double inverseFourierImg = 0.0;
    double degreeValue,cosValue,sinValue;
   // double inverse = inverseFourier;
    for(int rowm = 0; rowm < rows; rowm++ )
    for(int coln = 0; coln < cols; coln++ ) {


        inverseFourierImg = 0.0;
        inverseFourierReal = 0.0;
        for(int rowk = 0; rowk < rows; rowk++ ) {
           for(int coll = 0; coll < cols; coll++ ) {



           degreeValue  = 2. * PI * (float(rowk*rowm)/rows + float(coll*coln)/cols);
           cosValue  = cos(degreeValue);
           sinValue  = sin(degreeValue);

           inverseFourierReal += cosValue * fourierImageReal[rowk][coll] - sinValue * fourierImageImg[rowk][coll];
           //inverseFourierImg += (cosValue * fourierImageImg[rowk][coll] + sinValue * fourierImageReal[rowk][coll]);
           //cout<<inverseFourierReal;

            }

       }

        invr_FourierReal.at<double>(rowm,coln) = abs((inverseFourierReal) / (sqrt(rows*cols)));
       // invr_FourierReal.at<double>(rowm,coln) = double(inverseFourierReal) / (sqrt(rows*cols));
        //invr_FourierImg.at<double>(int(rowm),int(coln)) = double(inverseFourierImg) / (sqrt(rows*cols));


    }
```

You can see the output image here:

[image: img]

Edit:
I have changed the code and you can see new output. it is upside down.
[image: imgg]
I used Lena image for the input

P.S sorry for my poor English.

Comment: how can we help when we do not see the part of code you are doing this with? most likely similar problem to this: [Implementing 2D inverse fourier transform using 1D transforms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40816757/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for your respond. I have added the piece of code which i used for inverse transformation

Comment: Added answer at least that is how I see it.

Comment: I have corrected my mistake. Could you please look to the new output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Weird mirrored blend**

What is `fourierFilterImg`? are you doing some kind of convolution instead of **IDFT**? Also hope `invr_FourierReal` is not the same memory place as `fourierImageReal`. My bet is that it is just a copy/paste typo so I would change this line:

```
inverseFourierReal += (cosValue * fourierImageReal[rowk][coll] - sinValue * fourierFilterImg[rowk][coll]);
```

To:

```
inverseFourierReal += cosValue * fourierImageReal[rowk][coll] - sinValue * fourierImageImg[rowk][coll];
```

Also I hope your input image is correctly **DFT** transformed and in complex domain.

**[Edit1] inversion of X,Y**

That can be just not the same counting of `row,col` direction for **DFT** and **IDFT** somewhere. Images usually have `Y` axis going down and `X` axis going right. If it is just upside down then just invert the one that is wrong.

If the problem is in **IDFT** then just change:

```
invr_FourierReal.at<double>(rowm,coln)
```

to:

```
invr_FourierReal.at<double>(rows-rowm-1,cols-coln-1)
```

But my bet is that it is just inverted during loading or rendering and **DFT/IDFT** has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Thanks. It was just typo. I am trying to do inverse fourier transform than i will do "Filtering in frequency domain".

Comment: Great thanks to you. It is working know. I will try filtering.