# Gaussian Blur Glitching/Segmentation

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision, convolution, gaussianblur

I'm trying to implement a Gaussian Blur from scratch (using C++). In the code below I've hard-coded the Gaussian kernel I'm using. I only kept one dimension as I'm trying to use the optimization I've read about where you can do a horizontal convolution pass and a vertical one over that to make your blur more efficient. Unfortunately, I'm running into some issues. Here is my code:

```
float gKern[5] = {0.05448868, 0.24420134, 0.40261995, 0.24420134, 0.05448868};
int** gaussianBlur(int** image, int height, int width) {
    int **ret  = new int*[height];
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        ret[i] = new int[width];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                ret[i][j] = (gKern[0] * image[2][j]) + (gKern[1] * image[1][j]) + (gKern[2] * image[0][j]) + (gKern[3] * image[1][j]) + (gKern[4] * image[2][j]);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                ret[i][j] = (gKern[0] * image[1][j]) + (gKern[1] * image[0][j]) + (gKern[2] * image[1][j]) + (gKern[3] * image[2][j]) + (gKern[4] * image[3][j]);
            } else if (i == (height - 2)) {
                ret[i][j] = (gKern[0] * image[i - 2][j]) + (gKern[1] * image[i - 1][j]) + (gKern[2] * image[i][j]) + (gKern[3] * image[i + 1][j]) + (gKern[4] * image[i][j]);
            } else if (i == (height - 1)) {
                ret[i][j] = (gKern[0] * image[i - 2][j]) + (gKern[1] * image[i - 1][j]) + (gKern[2] * image[i][j]) + (gKern[3] * image[i - 1][j]) + (gKern[4] * image[i - 2][j]);
            } else {
                ret[i][j] = (gKern[0] * image[i - 2][j]) + (gKern[1] * image[i - 1][j]) + (gKern[2] * image[i][j]) + (gKern[3] * image[i + 1][j]) + (gKern[4] * image[i + 2][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    int** temp = image;
    image = ret;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                ret[i][j] = (gKern[0] * image[i][2]) + (gKern[1] * image[i][1]) + (gKern[2] * image[i][0]) + (gKern[3] * image[i][1]) + (gKern[4] * image[i][2]);
            } else if (j == 1) {
                ret[i][j] = (gKern[0] * image[i][1]) + (gKern[1] * image[i][0]) + (gKern[2] * image[i][1]) + (gKern[3] * image[i][2]) + (gKern[4] * image[i][3]);
            } else if (j == (width - 2)) {
                ret[i][j] = (gKern[0] * image[i][j - 2]) + (gKern[1] * image[i][j - 1]) + (gKern[2] * image[i][j]) + (gKern[3] * image[i][j + 1]) + (gKern[4] * image[i][j]);
            } else if (j == (width - 1)) {
                ret[i][j] = (gKern[0] * image[i][j - 2]) + (gKern[1] * image[i][j - 1]) + (gKern[2] * image[i][j]) + (gKern[3] * image[i][j - 1]) + (gKern[4] * image[i][j - 2]);
            } else {
                ret[i][j] = (gKern[0] * image[i][j - 2]) + (gKern[1] * image[i][j - 1]) + (gKern[2] * image[i][j]) + (gKern[3] * image[i][j + 1]) + (gKern[4] * image[i][j + 2]);
            }
        }
    }

    image = temp;

    return ret;
}
```

The first pass (the first for block) seems to work fine as when I comment out the second block I do get a slightly blurred image. But when I use both I get a choppy "weird" image, as shown below (the first image is my [grayscale input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGxLY.jpg), the second is the [choppy output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsKNj.jpg)):

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the pointers you use.

The function starts with `image` as input and `ret` as the intermediate result of the first step.

The second step must use `ret` as input, and write either to the original input (overwrite the input image) or to a new image. Instead, you do:

```
int** temp = image;
image = ret;
// read from image and write to ret
image = temp;
return ret;
```

That is, going into the second pass, both `image` and `ret` point to the same data, you then read and write to the same data. Next you do a pointer assignment that has no effect (`image` is never used after this) and return the intermediate buffer.

If you want to write to the input image, simply swap the `image` and `ret` pointers before the second pass:

```
std::swap(image, res);
```

If you don’t want that, you’ll have to `new` another image to write into.

---

It is bad practice to use an array of arrays to store an image. If you look into the source code of any image processing library, you’ll see they allocate a single large memory block for the image, which stores all image rows concatenated. Knowing the width of the image, you know how to index: `image[x + y*width]`.

This not only simplifies code (no loops to allocate a single image), but it also greatly speeds up code: there is no pointer lookup any more, and all data is close together to best use the cache.

This whole code can be simplified significantly by following the advice above: the two passes can be done with the same code. Write a function that filters one line of the image. It takes a pointer to the first pixel, a line length, and a step (which is 1 for horizontal lines, and `width` for vertical lines). This 1D function is then called in a loop over the lines in another function.  This second function is then called once to do the horizontal pass, and once to do the vertical pass. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063757/7328782) for details.)

In this situation, it is easy to avoid intermediate images by using a buffer of the size of a single image line. Write into that buffer, then copy the whole line back into the input image after it is filtered. This means you have a single buffer of size `max(width,height)` rather than a buffer of size `width*height`.

The 1D filter function can also be simplified. That loop should not have any if statements, they will significantly slow down. Execution. Instead, special-case the first two and last two pixels, and loop only over the bulk of the pixels where you don’t have to worry about the image edge.

Comment: even if i delete those lines and change all the references to image to ret in the second block i get the same results though? i will look at the link you sent though and try to implement the 1d implementation, thanks for the help!