# Which method is Matlab/Octave using for conv2 function?

Tags: c, matlab, image-processing, fft, convolution

Which method is Matlab/Octave using for `conv2` function?

Is it:

- Fast Fourier Transform
- 3 or more for-loops e.g classical iteration
- Other?

I'm looking for the fastest method to do `conv2`. I'm going to write C code for it.

Comment: MATLAB has excellent [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html#bvgtfpe) and Octave's [source code](https://github.com/gnu-octave/octave/blob/default/libinterp/corefcn/conv2.cc) is publicly available.

Comment: 3 for loops are uniquely and exclusively used to teach students that they are bad.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes. What do you prefer?

Comment: I am unclear what you mean. My point was that no commercial implementation of convolutions would do loops. My preference is not very relevant to what Mathworks implements.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm asking what method do you prefer. If loops are bad for conv2D, how should I then do it?

Comment: Again, not my preference. Everyone in the world uses FFT.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes. I'm using FFT when I do 2D convolutional, but is that a optimal solution? Because FFT2D is multiple FFT1D.

Comment: @euraad I can repeat myself if you want, but I really won't change the answer. 2D conv is 4 for loops. FFT is faster proven by theory, not just trial and error.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes. 2D conv is 4 loops, I agree. That's O(N^4). I have heard that conv2 by using FFT is much slower than regular classical loops. That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: And you are also not accepting the answers! If that is the case, and you still are in doubt, implement it and measure it yourself, I have already given an answer 4 times. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`conv2` implements the direct method (i.e. 4 loops). This is not O(*n*<sup>4</sup>), it is O(*nk*), with *n* the number of pixels in the image and *k* the number of non-zero pixels in the kernel.

The FFT implementation is O(*n* log *n*), independent of *k*, but the constant is quite large, so you need a large *k* to make this more efficient than the direct implementation.

You can simply test this by comparing the time it takes to compute `fft2(img)` vs `conv2(img,ones(3,3))`:

```matlab
img = ones(1024,1024);
k = ones(3,3);
timeit(@()fft2(img))
timeit(@()conv2(img,k,'same'))
```

```
ans =
    0.0059

ans =
    0.0015
```

Computing the convolution through the FFT requires 3 times the `fft2` call, plus a complex-valued multiplication, so would be more than 12 times slower than the direct implementation in this case.

You can also see that `conv2` time increases as the kernel size increases:

```
>> k = ones(7,7); timeit(@()conv2(img,k,'same'))
ans =
    0.0066

>> k = ones(19,19); timeit(@()conv2(img,k,'same'))
ans =
    0.0152
```

This would not be the case if it were to use the FFT convolution.

---

Note that MATLAB's implementation of the convolution is extremely efficient, it is hard to match this with your own C++ code. Still, even with a naive implementation, you don't want to use the FFT unless your kernel is quite large. If you do want to implement this yourself, see [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063757/7328782) for some tips on how to efficiently implement convolution.

---

If you use the FFT to implement the convolution, you need either to accept the periodic boundary condition, or pad the image sufficiently to avoid boundary effects. Though you need this padding in the direct method as well if you don't want to assume zeros outside the image, like `conv2` does (which is not at all useful).

---

#### Alternatives

For some kernels, there are much more efficient implementations than either the FFT or the `conv2` method:

- If the kernel is separable, you can apply 1D convolutions along image lines, then along image columns, to get to the final result in a strongly reduced computational effort (if the kernel is `n`-by-`m`, you'd do `n+m` instead of `n*m` multiplications and additions.
- If the kernel has uniform weights (as in the example I used above) then you can apply it with a cost independent of the number of pixels in the kernel. As you shift the kernel over, you subtract pixels exiting the kernel on the left, and add pixels entering the kernel on the right.
- If the kernel is a Gaussian or a Gabor kernel, you can also use well-known IIR implementations (which have a cost independent of the size of the kernel). IIR = infinite-impulse response.

---

#### Gaussian filters

DIPlib has [three implementations of the Gaussian filter](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/linear.html#dip-Gauss-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-FloatArray--dip-UnsignedArray--dip-String-CL-dip-StringArray-CL-dip-dfloat-): FIR (the direct method, as a series of 1D filters along each axis), IIR, and FT (using the FFT). Here's a comparison of their timing for a 2048x2048 image, for different sigma (using the DIPimage toolbox that directly calls the DIPlib functionality):

```matlab
img = randn(2048, 2048, 'single');
sigma = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 20];
t = zeros(numel(sigma), 3);
for ii = 1:numel(sigma)
    t(ii, 1) = timeit(@()gaussf(img, sigma(ii), 'fir'));
    t(ii, 2) = timeit(@()gaussf(img, sigma(ii), 'iir'));
    t(ii, 3) = timeit(@()gaussf(img, sigma(ii), 'ft'));
end

clf
set(gca, 'FontSize', 12)
plot(sigma, t * 1000, '.-', 'LineWidth', 1)
legend({'FIR', 'IIR', 'FT'})
xticks(sigma)
xlabel('Sigma of Gaussian (kernel is 2\lceil 3\sigma\rceil + 1)')
ylabel('Time (ms)')
```

[image: Timing comparisons for the three Gaussian implementations in DIPlib]

- FIR:

  - The 1D kernel size is `2*ceil(3*sigma)+1`.
  - This implementation takes advantage of the fact that the kernel is symmetric, so instead of doing `k` multiplications and additions, it does `k` additions and `k/2` multiplications. But other than that the code is fairly straight-forward (e.g. it's standard-compliant C++, no SIMD instructions are explicitly used, though the compiler should be using those when appropriate).
  - This is not linear in time, as you'd expect, because when applying the filter along the columns, the cache is used less optimally. So for larger sigma the memory access becomes a relatively larger cost.
- IIR:

  - This implementation is quite old, from 1998, plain C.
  - The IIR filter is a 1D filter applied along each axis in turn, like the FIR filter.
- FT:

  - For the FFT this used PocketFFT (I can build DIPlib with FFTW, but on my machine, an M1 Mac, that doesn't make much of a difference because FFTW doesn't have code specific to the M1 chip).
  - It uses only two FFTs: one forward for the image and one backwards for the result. The kernel itself is not transformed, but generated directly in the frequency domain. The Gaussian being separable, you can generate the 1D kernel and multiply it to both columns and rows of the FFT.
  - This method is slower for smaller sigma because it generates the kernel in the frequency domain, where larger sigmas produce smaller kernels (more zeros to multiply with).

---

#### Sobel filters

The Sobel filter is 3x3 but has only 6 non-zero weights. 6 multiplications and additions are very cheap to apply, it is never, ever cheaper to compute an FFT, let alone three. Note that traversing the image is the most expensive part here (it requires fetching the data from memory, which takes more time than 6 multiplications and additions). If you want to compute both derivatives, it is worth while combining them into the same loop over the image, to best use the cache.

Comment: I tried to use FFTPack with FFT2 for conv2 and got about 0.5 seconds in run time. Then I tried MKL library with the same thing. Then I got 0.075 seconds in run time. So that means, If I'm using you way to implement conv2, e.g 4 * for-loops, it will be faster?

Comment: Do you have any example code in C for `conv2`, or do I need have some kind of very optimized C code for `conv2` if it's going to meet the FFT2D?

Comment: MKL is 7 times faster than FFTPack from Pretty Fast FFT...only in the 2D case. Not in the 1D case. My kernel sizes is about 6*n where n can be like between 1 and 10 and for sobel operator, it's 3x3 kernel.

Comment: I don't put in in out-of-bounds test when I do my loops in C. I'm using pattern recognition for image classification. In my recognition algorithm, there are `imgaussfilt` in C code and `sobel` in C code. Perhaps A sobel operator can I do with simple for-loops instead of FFT. But for the `imgaussfilt` C code, I think FFT2D might perform well. I don't know...The kernel is 60x60 sometimes. That's quite large

Comment: By the way, good answer!

Comment: Thank you. I prefer to write my own libraries, self educational purposes. So you are saying that FFT2D is quite bad if I want to blurr an image?

Comment: And one `ifft2` as well: https://pastebin.com/vy5kwkXE Yes, the FFT is easy to implement and `CMSIS` got support for it. That's why I think it might be useful because a `conv2` with a large kernel e.g 10x10 or larger with the `same` parameter activated, might take a lot of CPU power, compared to hardware optimized FFT2.

Comment: But I will definitely think about the `sobel` operator, if regular vanilla 3-4 for-loops can beat hardware optimized FFT2.

Comment: Smart! I will do that! Never thought about that.

Comment: So what conclusion should we say, hardware optimized FFT performs better than regular vanilla iterations?

Comment: @euraad I've deleted all my comments here, and added the information to the answer instead. I've included some hints for computing the Sobel filters as well. Good luck with your implementation!

Comment: Seems that I was wrong! Great answer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri That's what I was wondering about ;)

Comment: Cris: Thank you. I will look at FIR-filter if it can be useful for me. Also, about the `sobel` kernels. It does not work to pre-FFT2 the kernels because the kernel augmenting its size

Comment: Hi again! I compared conv2 with FFT by using regular plain C code and Intel Math Kernel Library for FFT2D. Math Kernel Library was 1-2 milliseconds faster when the conv2 kernel was 3x3. Barley faster.

Comment: @euraad For a 3x3 kernel, no FFT is going to be similarly fast to a reasonable implementation of the direct convolution. If it is, you need to fix your convolution code. I suggest you post your convolution code on [codereview.se] to get tips on how to improve it. (Or search there for reviews of convolution code, there should be quite a few already).

Comment: If you wonder how the code looks like: https://pastebin.com/KfGvpKT1

Comment: I might be in need of gaussian bluring. Do you have a source for FIR filter in C code?

Comment: @euraad With `src_j = max(0, j - edge_cols);` and `for (; kernel_j >= 0 && src_j < src_cols; …)` you’re doing an out-of-bounds check for every single pixel read. This is incredibly expensive, and only meaningful for a handful of pixels at the edge of the image. If you get rid of those tests, it’ll be significantly faster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063757/7328782

Comment: @euraad This is the implementation of the Gaussian filter in DIPlib that I use: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/src/linear/gauss.cpp (FIR stands for Finite Impulse Response, this is the direct convolution implementation). But you’ll have to chase functions across quite a lot of files, this is a non-trivial implementation.

Comment: Thank you Cris! I have optimized my code and now the runtime difference between MKL's FFT2D for conv2 and my own plain C code conv2 is exactly the same. https://pastebin.com/U35d5tew

Comment: But for a kernel of size 61*61, then I cannot use plain C code for conv2. I need to use FFT. One problem I have is that I'm going to do conv2 on ARM microcontrollers and CMSIS-DSP library seems not to have conv2 nor FFT2D.

Comment: @euraad Yes, for a larger kernel you need to use the FFT. That is not a common situation though. The large kernels I’ve needed to use have usually been separable — more often than not it’s a Gaussian, but kernels with uniform weights can also be decomposed to reduce the computational cost. There are many small and compact libraries that you could be using, by the way.

Comment: Interesting. Are there any libraries for C that you recommend for me if I'm going to use conv2 for gaussian bluring? Speed is important here. I have been looking for a FIR-filter in CMSIS-DSP library, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go.

Comment: The sigma is going to be 5 or more, e.g kernel size 61*61 or larger for gaussian blurring.

Comment: @euraad Really? Please read the post you’re commenting on again. There’s a graph and everything! — The Gaussian is never implemented as a NxN kernel, but as a sequence of two 1D kernels of length N. That significantly reduces the computational cost. Now you need sigma to be 15 or so before the FFT version becomes more efficient, but there’s always the IIR implementation to make the very large Gaussians cheaper.

Comment: I understand that FIR filter is much better option for small kernels such as sigma 1 to 8. And those sigmas is in my region.

Comment: Cris, what do you think about `filter2` function in Matlab? It uses a FIR filter. https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html Can that be something useful for me?

Comment: @Cris, never mind of that `filter2`. It uses `conv2` function. I have found code for 2D filtering for FIR. https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33049-2-d-fir-filter-design?s_tid=srchtitle This is what I'm looking for. Clean code.

Comment: FIR stands for “finite impulse response”, it’s the type of filter that you can express as a kernel of a finite size. `conv2` applies a FIR filter. `filter2` does `conv2`,  but without mirroring the kernel (ie it computes correlation rather than convolution). I think it can also efficiently compute separable kernels.

Comment: Cris, I tried direct `conv` in `C` code for a separable kernel, and it was way much faster than direct `conv2` in `C` code. The winner was FFT 2D for `conv2` by using MKL-library (cheating). So now I know that `conv` for separable kernel is better than `conv2`.

Comment: I made three setups: 1: Large matrix and direct `conv2` with gaussian kernel - 20 seconds.  2: Large matrix and direct `conv` on rows and then on column - 1.02 seconds. 3: Using Math Kernel Library with FFT2D for `conv2` - 0.2 seconds. So If I'm using FFT 1D for `conv`...then it must be faster?

Comment: Cris, I don't really understand how `conv2` applies a FIR filter. Isin't the method about to create a `2D` kernel and then use matrix convolution? Or is the `FIR` the method to convolve with the matrix? As I understand, there are two ways to do matrix convolution: FFT or direct method. FIR/IIR/Gaussian is just kernels.

Comment: @euraad What `conv`/`conv2` implement is a FIR filter. IIR is when the convolution is defined using previous output values, say y(n)=x(n)-0.5y(n-1). IIR can be causal or anti-causal, depending on which direction you process in (left to right or right to left). A Gaussian IIR filter uses both a causal pass and an anti-causal pass. But this is a method where you can filter with a Gaussian of arbitrary size in a time independent of this size. Also, most analog filters are IIR filters, you can’t do `conv` in an analog circuit…

Comment: So FIR filter is the direct method I have always been used ? Like the plain C code ?