# How would a 1D gaussian smoothing filter look like as a convolution

Tags: image-processing, gaussian, smoothing, gaussianblur

I am new to image smoothing and I want to check if I understood correctly how a 2D image processing filter works. I learned that Gaussian smoothing filters can be described as convolutions. For a 2D image, the formula is:

g(x, y) = \omega \ast f(x, y) = \sum_{dx=-a}^{a} \sum_{dy=-b}^{b} \omega(dx, dy) \cdot f(x-dx, y-dy)

Now I am wondering if this is directly transferable to 1D. Would the formula look like this?

g(x) = \omega \ast f(x) = \sum_{dx=-a}^{a} \omega(dx) \cdot f(x - dx)

I think this can work for my case, as the Gaussian function is also separable from 2D to two 1D convolutions, but I am not entirely sure if the idea for the convolution formula stays the same.

Any feedback, if this is correct or not (then how) is appreciated!

Comment: There is no LaTeX support, please write the equations in a readable manner.

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian filters are separable. And as such you can extend or reduce them to any number of dimensions, as you did. So yes, you can implement a 1D Gaussian convolution as you did, and you can also extend it into as many dimensions as you desire.

However in practical terms you should implement convolutions through the Fourier convolution theorem – https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

For larger kernels and higher dimensions this will easily outperform the direct convolution. Also its more stable numerically.

Comment: More stable numerically than what? The direct sum? No, it cannot be, makes no sense. How can something that combines all values in the input image be more stable than something that does only local computations? If you double the number of samples, you halve the precision of the result of the FFT…

Comment: Also, just yesterday I was making the point that a Gaussian filter is never more efficient through the FFT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77304503/7328782