# 2D FFT what to do after converting both matrix into FFT-ed form?

Tags: c++, math, fft, convolution

Assume that I have 2 matrix: `image, filter;` with size `MxM and NxN`.

My regular convolution looks like this and produces matrix `output` size `(M-N+1)x(M-N+1)`. Basically it places the top-left corner of a filter on a pixel, convolute, then assign the sum onto that pixel:

```
for (int i=0; i<M-N; i++)
for (int j=0; j<M-N; j++)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for (int u=0; u<N; u++)
    for (int v=0; v<N; v++) 
        sum += image[i+u][j+v] * filter[u][v];
    output[i][j] = sum;
}
```

Next, to perform FFT:

1. Apply zero-padding to both `image, filter` to the right and bottom (that is, adding more zero columns to the right, zero rows to the bottom). Now both have size (M+N)x(M+N); the original image is at
   `image[0->M-1][0-M-1]`.
2. (Do the same for both matrix) Calculate the FFT of each row into a new matrix, then calculate the FFT of each column of that new matrix.

Now, I have 2 matrices `imageFreq` and `filterFreq`, both size (M+N)x(M+N), which is the FFT-ed form of the image and the filter.

But how can I get the convolution values that I need (as described in the sample code) from them?

Answer (score 1):

convolution between `A,B` using **FFT** is done by per element multiplication in the frequency domain so in 1D something like this:

1. **convert A,B by FFT**

   assuming the sizes are `N,M` of `A[N],B[M]` first zero pad to common size `Q` which is a power of 2 and at least `M+N` in size and then apply FFT:

   ```
   Q = exp2(ceil(log2(M+N)));
   zeropad(A,Q);
   zeropad(B,Q);
   a = FFT(A);
   b = FFT(B);
   ```
2. **convolute**

   in frequency domain use just element wise multiplication:

   ```
   for (i=0;i<Q;i++) a[i]*=b[i];
   ```
3. **reconstruct result**

   simply apply IFFT (inverse of FFT)...

   ```
   AB = IFFT(a); // crop to first N (real) elements
   ```

   and use only the first `N` element (unless algorithm used need more depends on what you are doing...)

**For 2D** you can either convolute directly in 2D (using 2 nested for loops) or convolve each axis separately. Beware that separating axises need also to normalize the result by some constant (which depends on dimensionality, resolution and kernel used)

So when put together (also assuming the same resolution `NxN` and `MxM`) first zero pad to (`QxQ`) and then:

```
Q = exp2(ceil(log2(M+N)));
zeropad(A,Q,Q);
zeropad(B,Q,Q);
a = FFT(A);
b = FFT(B);
for (i=0;i<Q;i++)
 for (j=0;j<Q;j++) a[i][j]*=b[i][j];
AB = IFFT(a); // crop to first NxN (real) elements
```

And again crop to `AB` to `NxN` size (unless ...) for more info see:

- [How to compute Discrete Fourier Transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26355569/2521214)

and all sublinks there... Also here at the end is 1D convolution example using NTT (its a special form of FFT) to compute bignum multiplication:

- [Modular arithmetics and NTT (finite field DFT) optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214)

**Also if you want real result then just use only the real parts of the result (ignore imaginary part).**

Comment: To compute 2D Inverse FFT, we apply IFFT to the columns, then apply IFFT to the rows, is that correct ?

Comment: @DukeLe order does not matter ... the result should be the same +/- rounding errors. However you need to normalize the result by multiplying the result with some constant  in order to achieve the same result as 2D IFFT ... in one of the links in that How to compute DFT is it described more...

Comment: Oh I thought if I do FFT column then row, then I have to IFFT row then column. Thanks, I'll check this and reply in a bit. But if possible, could you write a short Python or Matlab script to demonstrate this?