# What is largest number of multiplications needed to compute m^d mod n using the square-and-multiply algorithm when d is a k-bit exponent?

Tags: algorithm, math, binary

Which exponent(s) d will
require this many?

Would greatly appreciate any advice as to how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: What are you ideas about a solution?

Comment: You could experiment to gain intuition.

Comment: @nbro From reading I have determined that the multiply-and-square algorithm performs log2(d) number of multiplications  - which I am assuming is determined from the height or run time of its recursion tree?

Comment: That sounds like big-O of the number of multiplications. Your question isn't the sort of question for which a big-O solution is appropriate. For one thing, it has a number-theoretic component.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes, which is why I am stuck. I don't understand how to get the ceiling value.

Comment: Experiment. Write a program which keeps track. Run it for all 1-bit numbers, then all 2-bit, 3-bit, ... up to a given size. Do you see a pattern? If so, then prove it.

Comment: @JohnColeman now I'm on the same page, thanks

Comment: It seems a good first start would be to write down the algorithm, and then a recurrence relation defining the number of multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

assuming unsigned integers and simple power by squaring algo like:

```cpp
DWORD powuu(DWORD a,DWORD b)
    {   
    int i,bits=32;
    DWORD d=1;
    for (i=0;i<bits;i++)
        {
        d*=d;
        if (DWORD(b&0x80000000)) d*=a;
        b<<=1;
        }
    return d;
    }
```

You need just replace `a*b` with `modmul(a,b,n)` or `(a*b)%n` so the answer is:

1. **if exponent has `k` bits and `l` from them are set you need `k+l` multiplications**
2. **worst case is `2k` multiplications for exponent `(2^k)-1`**

For more info see related **QA**s:

- [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214)
- [modular arithmetics and NTT (finite field DFT) optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214)

Answer (score 1):

For a naive implementation, it's clearly the exponent with the largest Hamming weight (number of set bits). In this case `(2^k - 1)` would require the most multiplication steps: `(k)`.

For [k-ary window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#2k-ary_method) methods, the number of multiplications can be made independent of the exponent. e.g., for a fixed window size: `w = 3` we could compute `{m^0, m^1, m^2, m^3, .., m^7}` group coefficients (all `mod n` in this case, and probably in Montgomery representation for efficient reduction). The result is `ceil(k/w)` multiplications. This is often preferred in cryptographic implementations, as the exponent is not revealed by *simple* timing attacks. Any k-bit exponent has the same timing. (The reality is a bit more complex if it is assumed the attacker has 'fine-grained' access to things like cache performance, etc.)

Sliding window techniques are typically more efficient, and only slightly more difficult to implement than fixed-window methods. however, they also leak side channel data, as timing will be dependent on the exponent. Furthermore, the 'best' sequence to use is known to be a [hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation) problem.