# Implementation of Log function but for numbers represented as a string C

Tags: c, string, algorithm, logarithm

Is there a way to implement the log function witch works for string numbers without converting the string to a int?
example of string number:
char *stringNumber = "432"
the string represents only integers(whole Numbers) but they can be near infinitely long
the log should return an int as well(represented as a string) if i result is a float the decimal part should be removed (no rounding)

i know that for numbers you can implement:

```
int logn(int n, int x)
//n is the number , x is the base
{
    if (n <= r-1)return 0;
    return (1 + logn(n/x, x);
}
```

but for a string i have no idea how to do it

Comment: Is there a reason you *don't* want to convert the string to a number first?

Comment: Elian Dochev, Do you want to find the _binary_ log for a string with _decimal_ digits? Or find the _base_ log for a string with the _same_ base digits?  The first is hard, the 2nd is easy.

Comment: What is a "string number"? I would suggest to clearly specify the term, and provide some relevant examples (in particular, addressing range and precision).

Comment: Use [`strtod()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) to convert the string to a `double` (or `strtol()` to convert to an integer).

Comment: @ElainDochev Would all string numbers be integers, as the example suggests? What would the desired output look like?

Comment: @njuffa string number is string that contains only chars that are digits(char > = '0' && char <= '9')

Comment: @chux preferably if it can do any base logn(X)

Comment: @ElianDochev Is there a limit to the number of digits?  What would the output of the envisioned log function look like? An integer? A fixed-point number? A floating-point number? A string (what kind, given that logarithm generally produces results with a fractional component)? What base should the logarithm use? Base 10, base 2, base e, something else?

Comment: Edit the post to contain the information solicited by comments. Do not just answer in comments.

Comment: @dbush yes because it should be able to go to infinite aka without overflow and im not allowed to use libraries (for example cant use int64_t)

Comment: Elian Dochev, that broadens the goal.  It is already unclear.

Comment: @ElianDochev "not allowed to use libraries (for example cant use int64_t)" is unclear.  `int64_t` is only a type.  There is no library of functions  associated with it.

Comment: The base-two logarithms of many numbers are irrational. What do you want returned for, for example, log2(3)? Just the integer part, 1? Some number like 1.584? In a `double`, in a string using decimal, something else? How many digits should it provide? How accurate does it need to be?

Comment: @njuffa i should probably mention that the string will only be dealing with integers but they can be infinitely long , the log should return an int (represented as a string) as well

Comment: Are you using “int” to mean the actual C type `int` or as an abbreviation for “integer”? If the logarithm is 1.6, should the routine return 1 (truncated) or 2 (rounded) or something else?

Comment: If the integers can be "infinitely long", then the process of finding the logarithm, regardless of the method, will also be infinitely long. Perhaps you meant "arbitrarily long"?

Comment: @EricPostpischil just as a whole number not the int data type

Comment: @SGeorgiades by infinitely long i mean very very big

Comment: Your sample code doesn't use `x` at all.  What base is the number string in, and what is the base of the log?  If they're the same, the answer is trivial.

Comment: `int` (or `long long int` or `int256_t` when it is available) is not wide enough for "very very big" numbers. You need to **devise your own data structure and write your own functions** (sum, subtract, multiply, division, exponentiation, root, logarithms, ...) or use a library.

Comment: To answer the literal question in the post, “Is there a way to implement the log function”: Yes, you can perform long division, dividing the input number by the base and discarding the remainder. Doing this repeatedly and counting the repetitions produces the logarithm (the number of repetitions until the quotient is less than one is the greatest integer not greater than the logarithm). Techniques for long division taught in elementary school will work. They may be slow for large inputs.

Comment: There is no way to combine the logarithms of individual digits, you have to work with the whole number. That's going to require a library.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thx that's what i was looking for

Comment: you have to implement math operations on strings, for integers only its relatively easy: `a^x=b; x=log_a(b);` so just increment x until it `a^x` matches b ... so do a simple for loop like: `for (x=0,bb=1;bb<=b;bb*=a,x++);` so no recursion (which is not a good idea for strings) and only `+1,*` operations on strings you can use long multiplicaiton like you would compute it on paper...

Comment: implementing addition is simple ... in case you got really huge numbers you can have to use better multiplication like Karatsuba, or even NTT based like this one [`char* mul_NTT(const char *sx,const char *sy)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214) but that one is for really HUUUUGGEEEE numbers. The `log` itself might be speed up by binary search ... Your current approach is a BAD IDEA because you have division inside and recursion with string in tail that is just asking for Stack overflow, memory leaks and implementing and dealing with division is much harder than multiplicaiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @EricPostpischil for the answer
perform long division, dividing the input number by the base and discarding the remainder. Doing this repeatedly and counting the repetitions produces the logarithm (the number of repetitions until the quotient is less than one is the greatest integer not greater than the logarithm;
the answer of @pmg is also a good way to do it i thinks

Comment: That is still not going to work for "very *very* large numbers"

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string to a number

```
 char * numStr = "2.7";
 double num = strtod(numStr, NULL);
```

Comment: int str_to_int (char *scr)
{
    int number = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (scr[i]) {
    number = number * 10 + (scr[i] - '0');
    ++i;
    }
    return number;
}

Comment: @ElianDochev ok, that converts a string to an intgere too, so whats the question

Comment: @ElianDochev  You said "without converting the string to a int"; perhaps you meant "without converting the string to an int with a library function?

Comment: yeah that is correct but for that you still need your own datatype to store the potentially near infinite number

Comment: @ElianDochev OK now you asking a very different question , "how can I do math on a number like this - '7854389076547896543890976543'". For that you need a Big Integer library - google it

Answer (score -1):

Even your example function has typos in it. It appears you meant for it to return the integer part of the logarithm base x of n, with a floor function applied to the result. To accomplish this it would have to be:

```
int logn(int n, int x)           // n is the number, x is the base
{
    if (n <= x - 1) return 0;    // note: x, not r
    return (1 + logn(n / x, x);  // note: x, not 2 for the division
}
```

All that being said, I don't see any way of taking an arbitrary-base logarithm of a stringified number without converting it to a numeric value first. If you wanted only a base-10 logarithm, it would be possible.

Comment: you are right did not see that