# Fast modular exponentiation algorithm in c++ (for large numbers)

Tags: c++, algorithm, exponentiation

For educational purpose I'm developing c++ library for operating with large numbers represented as vectors of chars (`vector<char>`).

Here is algorithm that I am using for modular exponentiation:

```
BigInt modularExponentiation(BigInt base, BigInt exponent, BigInt mod) {
  BigInt x = B_ONE; // 1
  BigInt y = base;

  while (exponent > B_ZERO) { // while exponent != 0
    if (isOdd(exponent))
      x = (x * y) % mod;
    y = (y * y) % mod;
    exponent /= B_TWO; // exponent = exponent / 2
  }

  return (x % mod);
};
```

Is there any more efficent algorithm, or can this be improved (like parallelized with openmp)?

Comment: Instead of dividing the exponent (which I assume shifts all the bits) you could iterate through the bits without shifting them. You could also calculate `modularMultiplication(a, b, mod)` instead of `(a * b) % mod`

Comment: since this code works, consider codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: ```modularMultiplication(a, b, mod)``` is equal to: ```(a ** b) % mod```, so I cant replace ```(a * b) % mod``` with it.

Comment: modular **multiplication**. When you calculate `(a*b)%mod` in two steps, you calculate more bits than needed.

Comment: Ohh, I get it. Actually, I've tried to implement modular multiplication, but any algorithm I tried were for some reason slower than just ```(a*b)%mod```. Could you advise some modular multiplication algorithm?

Comment: there is also mongomery reduction to avoid `%` and also in some cases you can exchange the `a%b` with `(a>b)?a-b:a` see [Modular arithmetics and NTT (finite field DFT) optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214) inspect `modpow` in there however read the whole thread as it work only in specific situation where `a` is not bigger than `2*b`